# Start, Pause and Stop a Node.js process/loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, queue, rxjs

I'm in the process of building a bot that basically fetches images based on a search query(simple string), this bot needs to run 24/7, however multiple bots must be 'spawned' for different accounts, I already have the bot done, it basically takes in a config file and starts looping, however what would be the best approach to pause and stop this process?

I have looked into Node's `spawn child` functions, i have looked into RxJs's scheduler, but I am not sure which is the best bet, to approach something like this. Any insight would be helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to this particular problem, was to use `child_process.fork` and fork the secondary automation script, and use the `.on('message')` to process information back and forth for the state of the process.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you need to stop the whole process tree. The solution depends on which platform your code is running. On windows, we can run `taskkill` command to kill them, on linux/macos, we can utilize [tree-kill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tree-kill) package from npm. And first of all, you need to get the PID of the process to be killed. Here below is an implementation for reference:

```
const procTreeKill = require('tree-kill')
const cp = require('child_process')

const onMacOS = () => {
    return process.platform === 'darwin'
}

const onLinux = () => {
    return process.platform === 'linux'
}

const onWindows = () => {
    return process.platform === 'win32'
}

function kill(pid) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        if (onWindows()) {
            try {
                const options = {
                    stdio: [
                        'pipe',
                        'pipe',
                        'ignore',
                    ]
                }

                cp.execFile(
                    'taskkill',
                    ['/T', '/F', '/PID', pid.toString()],
                    options,
                    (error, stdout, stderr) => {
                        if (error) {
                            return reject(error)
                        }

                        return resolve(true)
                    }
                )
            } catch (error) {
                return reject(error)
            }
        } else if (onLinux() || onMacOS()) {
            try {
                procTreeKill(pid, 'SIGKILL', function (error) {
                    if (error) {
                        return reject(error)
                    }

                    return resolve(true)
                })
            } catch (error) {
                return reject(error)
            }
        } else {
            return reject(new Error('Platform unsupported.'))
        }
    })
}
```

You can use this function to kill the all bot process tree when you pass the PID of the 24/7 running process(the parent process of your bots), or you can just kill a worker process with its PID passed.

Answer (score 0):

You can run, pause and stop some function if you run it via sequential executor [nsynjs](https://github.com/amaksr/nsynjs). Please see [this example](https://github.com/amaksr/nsynjs/blob/master/examples/browser-ajax-seq.js) (and corresponding .html) for how to start (via nsynjs.run), pause (via nsynWait) and stop (via ctx.stop) execution.